# Why do i get a MongoDB duplicate key error with this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm parsing an array of objects from an api and then adding it to my collection on MongoDB.

I don't want to add something that is already there so i setup the code below to check if the _Id already exists. While the code seems to work ok and the server does not crash or anything, i get an error in the console saying there is a duplicate key.

If i do a console.log(i['_id'} after the if just to check that the if statement is working properly, it does work as intended. But when i use it to add stuff to mongoDB i get that error. The items are not being duplicated in the collection though so all is fine for that part. Is this a bug in MongoDB?

```
for (let i of alertData.data.items) {
        let id = G2Alerts.findById(i['_id'])
        if (i['_id'] === id) {continue}
        newAlerts = new G2Alerts({
            _id: i['_id'],
            equipmentId: i['equipmentId'],
            equipmentType: i['equipmentType'],
            stationId: i['equipmentId'],
            status: i['status'],
            alertType: i['alertType'],
            severity: i['severity'],
            openDate: i['openDate'],
            updateDate: i['updateDate'],
            initiatorEvent: i['initiatorEvent'],
            locationName: i['locationName'],
            city: i['city'],
            history: i['history'],
        })
    newAlerts.save()

    }
```

Comment: Why is `findById` returning an "id"? This "id" is then checked with `i['_id']` which is the _original value_ supplied to `findById`, which seems suspect for _multiple_ reasons. Then a new G2Alert is created with the _same_ `i['_id']`.. mkay. Logging `i['_id']` by itself won't show any issues; log the "id" as well.

Comment: tldr; it should probably be something more like: `for (let i of alertData.data.items) { if (G2Alerts.findById(i['_id'])) { /* already exists! */ continue; } /* does not exist - add new alert */ }`.

Comment: That was the answer, but i had to store it in a variable and use await to make it work. `for (let i of alertData.data.items) {let id = await G2Alerts.findById(i['_id'])   if (id) {continue;}`. Thank you so much!